# Rails Active Model - scope only objects which have existing members in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

This seemed trivial at first, but I can't get it right for some time now. The relation is trivial.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Now I would simply want to get all the Projects which have 1 or more tasks associated. Now to do this without any extended logic (preferably in one query). Backend is on Postgresql.

Edit:

Actually the best would be if I Could get Projects which have tasks with specific conditions. Like:

```
 task.status > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scope :having_tasks, :joins => :tasks, :select => 'distinct projects.*', :conditions => 'tasks.status > 0'

Comment: you could write this in a scope (in the project model):
  scope :with_tasks, :joins => :tasks, :conditions => 'tasks.project_id = projects.id'
then you can use: @projects = Projects.with_tasks

Comment: you are right, I just haven't noticed title and didn't write this as a scope ;) that happens when you open several tabs and go through all of them. my bad

Comment: Join automaticaly adds the condittion given, so there is no need to add :condition like above. The problem with this query is that it returns multiple rows for any given project. Grouping actually solves this, but Postgress wants me to add all 30 fields into group by clause, which is someting I do not really understand. Most  important, I messed up the question. What I really need istasks with specific conditions (updated question).

Comment: You are right - there is no need to add :condition like above. And join by default performs inner join, which means it only selects projects which have tasks. What you have to do is select distinct projects only. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, this actually solves the question. As for now, I made a instance method for Projects, which returns true if there are open tasks (task.status > 0), and I do simple 'Array.select' on the above query result to get the final result I need. Do you have any idea how to do this just by one SQL query?

Comment: try adding :conditions => 'tasks.status > 0' to the scope :)